# Interleaving values in single column of resultset

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Suppose we have values like this in 2 columns of the SQL table

```
HM        BOX_NO

A          1
A          2
B          2
B          3
C          3
```

I would like to output these table values like written below
How can I do that?

```
A
1
2
B
2
3
C
3
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you want the distinct values from HM with the values from BOX_NO, appearing beneath each values of HM.

You can do this.  Probably more complicated than you were expecting:

```
select val
from ((select distinct hm as val, 1 as ishm,
              dense_rank() over (order by HM) as ranking
       from t
      ) union all
      (select cast(box_no as varchar(255)), 0 as ishm,
              dense_rank() over (order by HM) as ranking
       from t
      )
     ) a
order by ranking, ishm desc, val
```

Comment: Your code is duplicating HM values  like A A 1 2.  How can you make HM distinct so that it becomes  A 1 2?

Comment: @user680865 . . . You are absolutely correct.  I "thought" distinct when writing it but I didn't put it in.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE #t
    ([HM] varchar(1), [BOX_NO] int);

INSERT INTO #t
    ([HM], [BOX_NO])
VALUES
    ('A', 1),
    ('A', 2),
    ('B', 2),
    ('B', 3),
    ('C', 3);

SELECT  item
FROM (
    SELECT  DISTINCT HM as item, HM as display_order
    FROM    #t  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  CAST([BOX_NO] AS VARCHAR(10)), HM + CAST([BOX_NO] AS VARCHAR(10))as display_order
    FROM    #t  
) a
ORDER BY display_order
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  Value = COALESCE(CAST(BOX_NO AS varchar(10)), HM)
FROM (
  SELECT          HM, BOX_NO FROM atable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT HM, NULL   FROM atable
) s
ORDER BY HM, BOX_NO
;
```

Here's a demo [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/682c1d/1).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Declare @t Table([HM] varchar(1), [BOX_NO] int);

INSERT INTO @t([HM], [BOX_NO])
VALUES
    ('A', 1),
    ('A', 2),
    ('B', 2),
    ('B', 3),
    ('C', 3);

;With Cte As(
Select 
      Rn
     ,HM
    ,BOX_NO
    ,HM_Grouping = HM + Cast(Rn As Varchar(1))
From (Select Rn = Row_Number() Over(Partition By HM Order by HM),*
      From @t)x)
Select HM 
From
    (Select HM,Position = HM
    From Cte Where Rn = 1
    Union All
    Select Cast(BOX_NO As Varchar(1)),HM_Grouping
    From Cte)x
Order by Position
```

**Result**

```
HM
A
1
2
B
2
3
C
3
```